# Gatling - Validate Values in SOAP ResponseBoxy

Tags: scala, soap, wsdl, load-testing, gatling

I am looking to check a value that returns in the ResponseBody from a SOAP Web Service.

Here is a sample ResponseBody from Web Service:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
     <ns5:getUserResponse xmlns:ns5="http://<someservice>" xmlns:ns3="java:com.mywebservice">
     <ns3:resultCode>0</ns3:resultCode>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I have the following:

```
....//snipped for brevity
.check(regex("""<ns3:resultCode>(\d*)</ns3:resultCode""").saveAs("resCode"))
.check("""${resCode}""".in(0 to 200))
....//snipped for brevity
```

I get an error message on the fact that `.in` isn't available for a String type but I am unsure how else to validate that the response of an xml contains particular values.

Any assistance would be awesome, and anything else needed I should more than happily oblige. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I am using gatling version 2.0.0-M3a - Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [current 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/gatling/highcharts/gatling-charts-highcharts/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/), that's:

```
.check(regex("""<ns3:resultCode>(\d*)</ns3:resultCode""")
       .transform(_.toInt)
       .in(0 to 200))
```

With 2M3a, that's:

```
.check(regex("""<ns3:resultCode>(\d*)</ns3:resultCode""")
       .transform(_.map(_.toInt))
       .in(0 to 200))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using 2.0.0-M3a. I tried the above code and it resulted in: `38: error: value toInt is not a member of Option[String]`
`.check(regex("""resultCode>(\d+)<""").transform(_.toInt).in(0 to 200))`

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I was trying so many any other ways that just got ridiculous.